# Inserting images into DOM at specific intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a series of repeating `<p class="question">` and `<p class=answer>` within a `<section id="interview">`. Following every third answer, I would like to insert an image, the pathname for which is stored in an array:

```
array = ['../../directory/file-1.jpg', '../../directory/file-2.jpg];
```

So far, I have:

```
var interval = 3;
var questionCount = 9;
var imageCount = array.length;
var interview = $('#interview');
var self;

for (var i = interval; i < questionCount; i+=interval) {
    interview.find('p.answer:nth-of-type('+i+')').each(function() {
        self = $(this);
        for (var p = 0; p < imageCount; p++) {
            self.after('<img src="'+array[i]+'">');
        }
    });
}
```

Of course, this is giving me all the images in the array at every interval rather than the first image at the first interval, the second at the second, and so on. How do I need to alter this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the inner `for` loop.

```
var j=0;
for (var i = interval; i < questionCount; i+=interval) {
    var ans = interview.find('.answer').eq(i);
    ans.after('<img src="' + array[j] + '">');
    j++;
}
```

Comment: This appears to be giving me the same image at every interval, i.e. the first image in the array. I'd like to have the first image at the first interval, the second image at the second etc.

Comment: @Ryan I edited the code. Added a separate index variable for array. Try it now.

Comment: That doesn't appear to have made any difference unfortunately, same result as before.

Comment: @Ryan well made some changes check now.

Comment: Exactly the same unfortunately. Your solution has got me nearest out of all the suggestions but I'm still getting the first image in the array repeated rather than the first, then the second, then the third etc.

Comment: @Ryan try it now. Made a silly mistake of puting `j=0` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want after the third to have the first image from the array, after the sixth to have the second image, etc.

If so, you almost had it, just drop the loop when spitting out an image and use the index of which p you're on.

```
var interval = 3;
var questionCount = 9;
var imageCount = array.length;
var interview = $('#interview');
var self;

for (var i = interval; i < questionCount; i+=interval) {
    interview.find('p.answer:nth-of-type('+i+'n)').each(function() {
        self = $(this);
        self.after('<img src="' + images[i] + '">');
    });
}
```

You can actually simplify your code significantly if you use a little bit more jQuery.

```
var images = []; // images go here
var interval = 3;
$('#interview:nth-of-type(' + interval + ')').each(function (index) {
    $(this).after('<img src="' + images[index] + '">');
});
```

Note that I used the `each()` function's `index` which lets me very easily know which set of 3 I'm on, which I can just pass to the images array.

Here is an example of my shortcut (using messages instead of images):

```js
const messages = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
const interval = 3;

$('p:nth-of-type(' + interval + 'n)').each(function (index) {
  $(this).after('<p>' + messages[index] + '</p>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>A</p>
```

Comment: I love the simplification (why didn't I think of that?), however `undefined` is being returned as the img src in your example.

Comment: Sorry, I just copied your code and removed the loop. Updated so it should work now.

Comment: Updated that, now nothing at all. I changed `$('#interview:nth-of-type(' + interval + ')')` to `$('p.answer:nth-of-type(' + interval + ')')` thinking that might be the solution but still no change, unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, I had a few small flubs. I added an `n` after the interval (so it'll be like `3n`). I also changed `insertAfter` to just `after` (if I wanted to use insertAfter, I should have switched the parameters around). Also, `index` is the first parameter of the `each` callback, not the first. Yay writing untested code. =p

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
interview.find('p.answer:nth-of-type('+interval+')').each(function(index) {
        self = $(this);
        $('<img>').attr('src', array[index]).after(self)
    });
```

and remove BOTH loops

Comment: Actually, the correct way is `$('<img>').attr('src', array[index]).insertAfter(self)`. (Why the correct? For safety reasons, that's all. But `self.after('<img src="' + array[index] + '">) works too`). Also, you can move the `self = $(this);` to inside the `after()`/`insertAfter()` call.

Comment: How is `interval` being iterated upon in your example?

Comment: @Ryan the nth-of-type does the iteration, and the index variable keeps track of how many you've visited so far.

Answer (score 0):

Get the answers and go with an iterator to every third of them:

```
var answers = interview.find('p.answer:nth-of-type('+i+')');
for (var answerIndex = 2; (answerIndex < answers.length) && (((answerIndex + 1) / 3) < array.length); answerIndex += 3) {
    $(answers[answerIndex]).after('<img src="array['+((answerIndex + 1) / 3)+']">');
}
```